# Crystal Reports distinct values in Report Footer

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I created a report that has a field for transcode in the details portion.  Transcode can have different values,

**`R, OT, H, or V`**

I would like to display this in the report footer for each of my transcodes with the total count of each

For example the line below is how I would like my output:

```
R      15           $Amount
OT      7           $Amount
H       9           $Amount
V       2           $Amount
```

There are some instances where some of these transcodes won't exist in the details section so it could just be `R` and `OT` and **no** `H` or `V`.

Is there a way I can do this without creating a variable for each of the transcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be dynamic, add a cross-tab object to the `report footer`:

[image]
Add the `transcode` field to the **Rows** section.

[image]
Note the **Summarized Field** settings.

Otherwise, you could create 8 running-total fields: 4 for the counts and 4 for the amounts:

[image]

- Set **Field to summarize** and **Type of summary**  to the desired values
- Set **On change of field** to `transcode`.

Comment: Thank you.  I have never worked with cross-tabs before, so I wasn't sure this functionality existed.  This is the second Crystal Question you have answered in three days.  I appreciate it.